# Cancel a link event in iframe that has a target="_parent" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe that shows a website on another domain that has links in it that have `target="_parent"` attributes. So instead of loading the link in the iframe, it redirects the whole page. Is there a way to catch this event, cancel it, and set the iframe's url to that link using jQuery or just straight javascript?

Comment: Maybe it will help you http://www.xlteam.pl/2010/10/07/javascript-onlocationchange-plugin-do-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

With browsers that support it, the best you could do is to use the [`sandbox`-attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

The iframe is not allowed to change the top location now unless you list `"allow-top-navigation"` in the attribute.

But instead of the link working in the iframe, the links don't work at all and a security error is logged in console:

http://jsfiddle.net/rRT6S/3/

Comment: Fortunately, it looks like IE10 will support this, and maybe even the next version of Firefox? http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox

Comment: Yeah looks that way. But still the links are not followed at all if they have `target="_parent"`, they will just be prevented. Is there any way you could ask the other site not to use `_parent` ?

Comment: I wish. I'm just playing around with creating a subreddit chat feature for reddit in my free time. I guess it wouldn't hurt to send them an email. I know Reddit is known for being community driven.